# Jmeter: While Controller, CSV Data Set, If Condition (x users, n data)

Tags: http, if-statement, while-loop, jmeter

How do run a while controller, for X number users for N number of data set?

CSV Data set

columnA,columnB

A,1001

B,1002

C,1003

D,1004

```
Test plan
¦__Group Thread — (User Count –> 4)
    ¦_While Controller (${__javaScript("${columnA}" != "",)})
        ¦_CSV Data Set (Recycle on EOF=False &, Stop thread on EOF= False)
            ¦_If condition (${columnA} != ”EOF”)
                ¦_Http request 1    
                ¦_Http request 2
```

I want to run for 4 users, 4 times each. i.e. 16 times * 2 http request.

But, my thread is running only 1 iteration per user.

How do I configure/plan my thread so that the Group thread runs for 4 users for all the data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the default [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) of the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) JMeter will read the next value from the CSV file with each user on each iteration.

You're making the things way too complicated, you can simplify your test to:

1. [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group):

   [image]
2. CSV Data Set Config:

   [image]

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Indeed I was complicating :-).